# crystal report - image not showing up

Tags: iis-7, crystal-reports

i have licenced crystal report in my live site..i have kept img data field which is actually a byte stream. but it dosent shoe up..and when i export the file to pdf i can see the image...can any one  tell me if i am missing some iis configuration?? because in local which is VS2008 development env. not licenced i can see image...

Comment: I dont know .. which shoes are you using ? ;)

Comment: You may need to show some code

Comment: can u tell me what iis setting is needed for image handler????

Answer (score 0):

only thing I can think of is that there may be a dll problem since it is clearly accessing the img file when it does the export. Try adding a Refresh() and checking that all of the libraries are the same for release and development environments as it is possible that a dll bug is causing the img only to be grabbed when the pdf is created